# Flutter error: Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'FilePickerResult'

Tags: flutter, post, multipartform-data, filepicker.io

I am trying to send some data and a file to my node js server. The file is a .txt file and I am using FilePicker to get the file and MultiPartRequest to send it.

This is the Widget with the text forms and the attachment button:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Crear una nueva tarea'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
      ),
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginFormProvider>(
          create: (context) => LoginFormProvider(),
          child: Consumer<LoginFormProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
            final loginFormProvider =
                Provider.of<LoginFormProvider>(context, listen: true);
            return Container(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Center(
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 370),
                    child: Form(
                      key: loginFormProvider.formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            onChanged: (value) =>
                                loginFormProvider.title = value,
                            decoration: buildInputDecoration(
                                hint: 'Enunciado',
                                label: 'Enunciado de la tarea',
                                icon: Icons.title),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            onChanged: (value) =>
                                loginFormProvider.date = value,
                            cursorColor: Colors.green,
                            decoration: buildInputDecoration(
                                hint: 'Fecha limite',
                                label: 'Fecha limite de entrega',
                                icon: Icons.date_range),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                final result =
                                    await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                  type: FileType.custom,
                                  allowedExtensions: ['txt', 'docx'],
                                );
                                final file = result!.files.first.name;
                                value.setFile(result);
                              },
                              child: Text('Seleccionar archivo')),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          CustomOutlinedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                if (value.file == null) return;
                                value.makePostRequest(loginFormProvider.title,
                                    id, teacherID, loginFormProvider.date);
                                
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              text: 'Crear Tarea'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
          })),
    );
  }
```

And I am trying to send the request as follows in this class:

```
class LoginFormProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var file;
  String role = '';
  String id = '';
  String lastname = '';
  String firstname = '';
  String password = '';
  String tid = '';
  String name = '';
  String title = '';
  int teacherid = 0;
  int subjectid = 0;
  String date = '';

  bool validateForm() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future setFile(txt) async {
    this.file = txt;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }

  Future makePostRequest(
      String title, int subjectid, int teacherid, String limitDate) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/newHomework');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'};
    File fileByte = this.file;
    Uint8List data = await fileByte.readAsBytes();
    List<int> list = data.cast();
    request.files
        .add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('text', list, filename: 'tarea1'));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.fields['title'] = title;
    request.fields['limitDate'] = limitDate;
    request.fields['subjectid'] = subjectid.toString();
    request.fields['teacherid'] = teacherid.toString();
    request.fields['ext'] = '.txt';

    var res = await request.send();
    return res.stream.bytesToString().asStream().listen((event) {
      var parsedJson = json.decode(event);
      print(parsedJson);
    });
  }
}
```

And I am getting `Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'FilePickerResult'`

I do not know how to fix this to send the file... Any ideas on how to go through this?

Comment: required the type of file but you are returning the FilePickerPickerResult. Also share the full code because I am not seeing the makePostRequest in the function being called.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I have updated the question with the button that sends the data, its a custom button called `CustomOutlinedButton`.

Comment: Did you resolve it. because you are returning FilePickerResult and it want the File.

Comment: No, I am getting the listed error, the code you're seeing is the code I am running, but when I tap on the CustomOutlinedButton throws the `Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'FilePickerResult'` error

Comment: @Irvin where are you getting ``` File fileByte = this.file```

Comment: Added the whole class, its a variable declarated inside the `ChangeNotifier` class which I use to validate the text forms and get their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is You are setting FilePickerResult instead of File.
[Edited using a different approach for the web.

```
ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                final result =
                                    await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                  type: FileType.custom,
                                  allowedExtensions: ['txt', 'docx'],
 withReadStream:
          true,

                                );
//Edited Part 
                      var file = result!.files.single;                              
                                value.setFile(file);
                              },
                              child: Text('Seleccionar archivo'))
```

and also

```
 PlatformFile file = null;

 Future setFile(PlatformFile txt) async {
    this.file = txt;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
```

```
 Future makePostRequest(
      String title, int subjectid, int teacherid, String limitDate) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/newHomework');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'};
    

    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile(
        "text", file.readStream, file.size,
        filename: "tarea1"));


    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.fields['title'] = title;
    request.fields['limitDate'] = limitDate;
    request.fields['subjectid'] = subjectid.toString();
    request.fields['teacherid'] = teacherid.toString();
    request.fields['ext'] = '.txt';

    var res = await request.send();
    return res.stream.bytesToString().asStream().listen((event) {
      var parsedJson = json.decode(event);
      print(parsedJson);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This line `File file = File(result!.files.single.path);` throws an error: `2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. Try adding the missing` and also says: `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>'.`

Comment: Did this: `File file = File(result!.files, result.files.single.name); value.setFile(file);` and got this error: `Error: Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'File$'`

Comment: @Irwin In which line do you getting the error.  ```value.setFile(result);```

Comment: I was getting the error here: `File file = File(result!.files.single.path);` so I updated it to `File file = File(result!.files, result.files.single.name);` Is it important to mention that this is Flutter Web?

Comment: @Irwin No, It is not. because the plugin is supporting all platforms. Including web. just updated the answer. try this.

Comment: Getting an error: `The argument type 'FilePickerResult' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.` I believe that is because on the line `value.setFile(result);` result is a FilePickerResult and is now being assigned to a File type.

Comment: Also... As per [link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) Flutter web cannot use `dart:io`. So I might have to refactor part of the function to adapt `dart:html`

Comment: @Irwin updated the example.

Comment: this won't work either because on line `value.setFile(result);` it throws an error: `The argument type 'FilePickerResult' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PlatformFile'.` Also it wont let me `PlatformFile file = null;` because `A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PlatformFile'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PlatformFile'.`

Comment: updated only need to change the ```value.setFile(result);``` to ```value.setFile(file);```

Comment: I managed to make it happen but couldn't have done it so without your help and time. Thank you for your patience ant the support @Shahryar Rafique.

Comment: your wecolme. @Irwin .